# Process builder - Create a child contact and keep it in sync with parent account on edit

Tags: process-builder

I want to create a contact every time an account with record type ='Landlord Account' is created. This contact will have the same name and billing address as the Landlord Account.

I also want to maintain any edits made to the account on the contact. So if billing address is edited on account, it should update billing address on contact.

Does this require two process builder processes? One for the create action, and one for the edit action? Or can I create this all with one process?

What are your recommendations?

Comment: I accomplished this with one process. First action is create contact and stamp checkbox on contact and account to identify landlord contact has been created. Second action is to update account child records with criteria only landlord contact checkbox = true. I also included validation rule on contact so users cannot edit fields on contact level that will be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single Process.

[image]

1. While selecting the Account object, Start the process should be 'when a record is created or edited' so that you can use it for both creation of Account and update of Account
2. First criteria is simple formula of isNew(). Action should be creating a Contact with Account details.
   [image]
3. Second criteria should be checking the isChanged of all Billing Address. Action should be updating the Contacts with Mailing address with Billing Address.
   [image]

Hope it helps.